# Will an uninitialized local variable in a loop have the same value each iteration?

Tags: c++

Consider the following piece of code:

```
int l;
int k;
for (int i=0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    int j;
    if (i == 0) l = j;
    if (i == 1) k = j;
}
assert (l == k);
```

Does the assertion hold? The interesting piece is if the uninitialized variable can take different values in different iterations.

Some playing around with LLVM suggests that the assertion actually does hold: *is this actually guaranteed by the standard or if it is undefined and that it happens the way the LLVM compiler implements it?*

Comment: Please don't troll the community by requiring to define undefined behavior, thanks.

Comment: compiler error, undefined j, and assert (j==k)

Comment: @H2CO3: There is no undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ qPCR4vir: Sorry, assert(j=k) was a typo.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not trolling anybody here. If you don't want to help, then don't answer.

Comment: I like it when a language *prohibits* reading from an uninitialized variable. I guess that's what warnings are for in C/C++ ..

Comment: But the compiler can't know in the general case whether a variable is uninitialized or not. And performing a runtime check is a no-go in C (and for C++, but it's impossible to introduce anyway because of the backward compatibility).

Comment: @ipc Sure it can, just like Java or C# which prohibit this during compilation *without* runtime checks. A local variable that is not *guaranteed* to be initialized in a code-path *cannot* be used. Since accessing an uninitialized local variable is *UB*, this - in any case I have run into - seems perfectly sensible behavior. (Unless, of course the UB/IDB *is* desired .. but that should be the rare exception and not the norm. Anyway, not C/C++, but I like it when languages reduce the number of bullets.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to what you're *trying* to do: the value of `j` is indeterminate.  It's just whatever happens to be on the stack when it's declared, so the assertion does *not necessarily* hold.

---

**edit**: it was pointed out that, since `j` is likely on the same place on the stack every time it's allocated, what is the expected behavior of the value?

The fact that it's the same is just a fact of the implementation.  The standard states:

> **6.2.4** For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which
>   it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way.
>   (Entering an enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does
>   not end, execution of the current block.) If the block is entered
>   recursively, a new instance of the object is created each time. **The
>   initial value of the object is indeterminate. If an initialization is
>   specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration is
>   reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value becomes
>   indeterminate each time the declaration is reached.**

It's indeterminate.

**edit 2**: that was the C standard.  From C++:

> **6.7** Variables with automatic storage duration (3.7.2) are initialized each
>   time their *declaration-statement* is executed. Variables with
>   automatic storage duration declared in the block are destroyed on exit
>   from the block (6.6).

Comment: If it really is "whatever happens to be on the stack when it's declared", why would that value change between iterations?

Comment: Thanks, David, this is actually what I'm asking. LLVM puts j on the stack in the entry block and it stays there, so given the IR, it will not change, I'm just wondering if this guaranteed.

Comment: No you are not asking that. You are asking what guarantees the standard provides. This answer appears to assume that `j` is stored on a stack. And the standard says nothing about that.

Comment: Yes, so it is that LLVM happens to compile it this way but the standard does not guarantee it.

Comment: Right. In fact I cannot believe you will find a compiler for which your assertion fails. Because all implementations will be essentially the same, and stack based. But the standard doesn't guarantee anything about UB.

Comment: @HolgerWatt: a more interesting question now!  Updated.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, David and sheu. This answers the question completely. In case you're wondering, this entailed quite a realization for me. I'm implementing a software verification tool compiling C++ to LLVM IR and do the actual verification using the IR. But this actually really means that I'm not really verifying C++ code but the IR resulting from the compilation which may be different. Might be enough in practice, but I still need to be careful what I'm claiming.